# Fn key not properly working

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I have a problem with my fn keys. If I use my volume hotkeys thru fn key, it works immediately even without releasing the volume hotkey. Now the problem is when I used the brightness, touchpad, and monitor hotkeys. The brightness and multiple display projection hotkey is working but I have to release the key to make it work, the touchpad enable/disable and the monitor on/off isn't working. My laptop model is  **Asus X454L (intel core i3, nvidia geforce 820m, 4gb ram model)**  . Any solutions?

PS: I've used a non-asus charger. And I'm thinking it is the cause of the problem.

Comment: If the charger is the cause of the problem, you may not want to use it. The difference in voltage could literally blow up your computer. Does the problem present itself when the laptop is plugged in only?

Comment: Did you compare the specifications of the chargers before using it? Did the problem only start after using the charger? Are there any other keys not working?

Comment: No. The laptop is disconnected to that charger, and the problem still persist. I've also tried to removed the battery and let the unit drain its remaining power.

Comment: No, I didn't compare specs of the charger. But I've compared the input voltage required by the laptop and the voltage that the charger releases. Yes, the problem only started after using the charger and no, there are no other keys not working, just the fn+touchpad and fn+screen on/off

Comment: Check ASUS support site for the most recent version of their software and drivers. Fn shortcuts are usually controlled by vendor software. ATKACPI is package you want. If you already have recent version, try to reinstall it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys aren't working properly, it may require you to repair the hotkey utility.

1. Click on Start
2. Go to Control Panel > Program > Program and Features
3. Look for the ATK package entry
4. Right-Click > Repair

The <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys should start working again. If not, you may need to download an update from ASUS or there may be some physical damage.

Comment: Great! Glad to help. Please mark the question accepted so others will know it has been answered.